How to refer to the locations in lower depths of a waterbody (such as a lake)?
For a body of water (say, a lake), the location in the water with the greatest distance from the bottom can be called surface water. However, I'm looking for a word to describe the location of points in the lower depths of a lake. Let's say I select some points in the water at a depth of 10 meters. And want to say that the temperature at these points is lower than the temperature of the surface water.  Saying that the depth temperatures were lower than the surface temperature is concise, but it doesn't seem right. Since a dictionary like Longman has defined the depth as,

the distance from the upper surface of something, such as a river or a hole, to the bottom of it.

And something like depth temperature doesn't make sense. I want to refer to the points that are selected in lower depths several times, so I'm wondering if there is an alternative for referring to such points rather than saying something like the temperature in lower depths of the lake.
Edit:
To make it clear what I'm looking for for example in the academic papers the term surface water temperature was used many times. Furthermore, It is usual to use terms such as "surface water" in this context. I'm looking for an equivalence to refer to the points in depth of water. (In a sense, the opposite of "surface water")

Can you provide a cite for the terminology "surface water" with that meaning?  "the location in the water with the greatest distance from the bottom can be called surface water."  Do you mean the water that abuts the air, no matter how deep the water is at that location? Water "at the surface"?

Are you intending to refer to temperatures at several different depths, or only to contrast "surface temperature" with the temperature at the bottom of the lake / river / ocean?

"The temperature at depths of 5 metres and 10 metres".

@TimR  Ok the way I defined "surface water" might not be precise. But in the field that I'm working (water quality) the terms surface water and surface water quality was used many times.

@FumbleFingers I want to refer to several specified depths in lake in the academic context. The locations are not necessary at the bottom but in different depths in water.

@KateBunting I found it hard to explain what I'm looking for. Please see my edit for the clarification.

My suggestion still stands.

As @KateBunting says, you can refer to "The temperature at depths of 5 metres and 10 metres" OR singular "The temperature at a depth of 5 metres". Strictly speaking there probably isn't an "attributive adjective" (before the noun) form corresponding to "The surface water temperature", but in your relatively technical context I would have no problem with "The 5-metre and 10-metre temperatures" (with depth at the specified depth and water being contextually assumed). Is that what you're getting at?

@FumbleFingers Thanks for the explanation. Let's say I have selected three points in the lower depth of the water, the problem I face is that I need to refer to the temperature in the points in the water in general several times.  Say something like the temperature at lower depths of the lake was lower than the surface temperature. Using "lower depths of lake" many times makes the writing look bad and not concise (unlike saying surface temperature is very convenient in papers and concise).

Just refer to the surface temperature and the  subsurface temperature for two categories (there's no need to explicitly include the word water, since it's contextually obvious). That way, all your references (including the 10-metre temperature, etc.) can be "attributive adjectives" (used before the "head" noun temperature). None of this prevents you using other phrasings such as those suggested by KateBunting elsewhere in your text - just don't chop and change "for the sake of variety".

@FumbleFingers Thanks for the suggestion!

As has been pointed out in comments, you can refer to temperature at depths of 5 metres and 10 metres or singular temperature at a depth of 5 metres.
Strictly speaking there probably isn't a fully valid "attributive adjective" form corresponding to surface water temperature, but in OP's relatively technical context I see no problem with the 5-metre and 10-metre temperatures (depth and water being contextually assumed).
All temperatures collectively apart from the surface temperature can be referenced as subsurface temperature if only those two categories are relevant. That way, all the temperature references can be given in "attributive adjective" form (used before the "head" noun temperature).

Note the use of definite vs indefinite article.
"The depth" of a body of water is a measurement from surface to bed, taken at a particular place, and time of day if tides are involved or time of year if seasonal changes are involved.
So you'd say "The temperature at a depth of n meters" if you're measuring at a place other than at the bed.
Since such a temperature reading is taken at an arbitrary depth, there's no standard adjectival term for it, especially since the type of the body of water may vary.  Riverine terminology would be different from that used for oceans.

The technical terms for the different depths of water in a lake are:

The Littoral Zone (Shallow, nearshore area where sunlight reaches the bottom; supports aquatic plants and diverse wildlife)
The Limnetic Zone (Open, sunlit water away from the shore; crucial for photosynthesis and supports plankton and fish)
The Profundal Zone (Deep, dark water beyond light penetration; colder with fewer organisms adapted to low light and oxygen.)
The Benthic Zone (Bottom region of the lake; includes sediment and is home to decomposers and detritus feeders)

There are also terms for different thermal layers:

The Epilimnion (Warm, upper layer)
The Metalimnion (Middle layer with a rapid temperature change)
The Hypolimnion (Deepest, cold layer; low in oxygen)

However, the common terms for the zones which you would expect to be used in general discussions among a broader audience are:

Surface water (The water at the top of the lake that is exposed to the air and sunlight)
Mid-water (The water layer between the surface and the deep water, where temperature and light start to decrease)
Deep water (The colder, darker water at the bottom of the lake)
Bottom water (The water at the very bottom of the lake, including the sediments)


As your paper uses the term 'surface water', it would make sense that you use the more common terms.
